# Is there a function for setting a password to a post?

Tags: functions

Like set_post_password( $post_id, $password ) or similar? I can't find anything. Do I have to make use of $wpdb?

Comment: Welcome to wpse! I personally never used this feature but WordPress comes with a option to set a password to posts. see [Using Password Protection](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-password-protection/)

Answer (score 0):

The password is a core field of a post, so it's updated with `wp_update_post()`, just like the title or content:

```
wp_update_post(
  array(
    'ID'            => 123,
    'post_password' => 'abc123',
  )
);
```